# get name of violated fk in plpgsgl exception handler

Tags: postgresql, exception, plpgsql

I wrote a plpgsql function to insert some data into a table. inserting into the table my violate one of two foreign key constraints.
i can catch the exception using "WHEN foreign_key_violation THEN" but how can i find out which FK was violated? is there a field accessible inside the plpgsql exception handler containing this information?

Comment: Why don't you check your constraints before insertion?

Comment: because in my opinion it is pointless to check for referential integrity if the rdbms checks again afterwards - it is more work for me to write, it is more work for the dbms to execute and it adds reduntancy which may get out of sync over time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of version 9.3 you can use CONSTRAINT_NAME to see which foreign key has been violated.

Details in the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/interactive/plpgsql-control-structures.html

Comment: Thank you - I had to figure out the correct Syntax - for future readers:WHEN foreign_key_violation THEN
        GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS l_constraint = CONSTRAINT_NAME;
        IF (l_constraint = 'name') THEN
            RAISE 'some message';